# CSS grid automated positioning

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a css grid and I need to position them but I want to do that automated

I want for every class `.twoColumns` for it to take place two columns but I don't want it static like the code below

```css
.box {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

I want it dynamic and automated like this

```css
.twoColumns {
  grid-column-start: n;
  grid-column-end: n+1;
}
```

Is it possible? Thanks in advance

Result I want to get

`.twoColumns`

`.a` `.c`

`.b` `.d`

right now I have something like

`.twoColumns` `.c`

`.a` `.d`

`.b`

It's vertical

[image: I need these titles (in the top) to take 2 places but automated to have them 1 common class]

I need these titles (in the top) to take 2 places but automated to have them 1 common class

Comment: Can you show the HTML code?

Comment: Are you open to using some framework/library like Bootstrap etc.?

Comment: Mark Schultheiss Nope I can't use libraries :/